# Is there a way to use UUIDs instead of id block allocation in JanusGraph?

Tags: janusgraph

I'm interested in ways to avoid [`id block allocation`](https://docs.janusgraph.org/basics/configuration-reference/#ids) in JanusGraph to improve performance and avoid wasting unused IDs (i.e. if you allocate 1M ids, use 100k and you need to restart - you waste 900k ids which cannot be reclaimed... ever).

Has anybody been able to replace the `integer ids` with maybe `UUID`s and ensuring all instance have unique `hostnames||instanceIds`?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe thats possible with janusgraph. I had a similar requirement to avoid collissions when using `ConfiguredGraphFactory` with elasticsearch index backend. Ids are longs by default and it lead to collisions unless there we maintain an index per graph in elasticsearch